# Sails how to transform string type in array to json

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have a simple REST application built in Sails and I want to save the correct data in a model  attribute of type `array`.

**Route to post**

`http://localhost:1337/locations/create?name=savassibeer&locations={latitude:23789472398.2344,longitude:2734637892.56756756}&locations={latitude:22.2344,longitude:2562.56756756,date:2014-02-15T11:00:00}`

**The result**

```
{
  name: "savassibeer",
  locations: [
    "{latitude:23789472398.2344,longitude:2734637892.56756756}",
    "{latitude:22.2344,longitude:2562.56756756,date:2014-02-15T21:49:23.084Z}"
  ],
  createdAt: "2014-02-15T21:49:23.084Z",
  updatedAt: "2014-02-15T21:49:23.084Z",
  id: "52ffe0e345d19ec72b4fac77"
}
```

How can I transform the strings in `locations` to a valid JSON Object and save it?

Comment: Just to be sure to get your issue: Do you want to ensure the items in `locations.locations` are valid JSON strings before saving, save every item as actual js object or just get the js objects for the json strings?

Comment: Plus: Which version of Sails / which Sails adapter do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to do this using URL shortcuts (i.e. hitting `/locations/create` in the browser).  They're not designed to do type-guessing.  If you want to save data this way, the answer is to write a custom `create` action in your Locations controller that will 1) validate the locations data as @marionebl mentions above, and 2) set the `locations` attribute as a Javascript array.

Comment: Would you set the locations attribute as an array in the controller, or the model?

Comment: @hamncheez the `locations` attribute in this model is `type: 'array'` (which is really just an alias for `type: 'json'`).  When you do `Locations.create()` in the controller action, that's when you'd set the `locations` value as an array (e.g. `Locations.create({locations: [{latitutde: 123, longitude: 456}, ... ]})`)